How to get data from join table and display in a Dynamics 365 form - combining multiple tables in a single form
Working in Dynamics 365 Sales. I have 3 tables with a many to many relationship between Members and Events, an event can have many members booked on it, and a member can be booked on many events:

Member
Event
Member_Event (join table)

How do I create a Form to show a specific single event, and show all members linked to this event?
I am quite new creating Dynamics 365 Solutions, and can't find any support documentation anywhere online or Youtube that gives me any clue on how should I approach this challenge?
Edit: In addition I need to be able to add new Members to the list associated with each Event. So within the Event form, a list of Members in the join table, and ability to add new members to this list.

Just configure the tables and the relationship (N:M) between them. You can find the associated view in the form's "Related" menu.

Thanks @HenkvanBoeijen that is very helpful. When I click the related item in the dropdown a Tab now appears with the linked data. I wonder if it's possible to make that Tab stay there all the time?

You can edit the main form and add a subgrid component to it.

Thank @HenkvanBoeijen - I will try the subgrid component. If you want to post the above items as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer :)

Step 1
Just configure the tables and the relationship (N:M) between them. You can find the associated view in the form's "Related" menu.
Step 2 (When the table of related needs to be displayed at all time.)
Edit the main form of table A and add a subgrid component to it displaying the related items of table B.

Here is a subgrids and quick create forms video with detailed instructions that solve the challenge completely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baRLW8bak9Q
